# play encoded stream in gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer

I used the following GStreamer pipeline to store my encoded stream in a binary file:

```
gst-launch v4l2src ! videorate ! video/x-raw-yuv, framerate=\(fraction\)10/1 \
  ! videoscale ! video/x-raw-yuv, format=\(fourcc\)I420,  width=640, height=480\
  ! ffmpegcolorspace ! x264enc ! fdsink > vid.bin
```

Now i want to play previously recorded files in GStreamer using the following pipeline:

```
cat vid.bin | gst-launch fdsrc ! ffdec_h264 ! autovideosink
```

But then it gives the following error:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/ffdec_h264:ffdec_h2640: Internal GStreamer error: negotiation problem.  Please file a bug at http://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=GStreamer.
Additional debug info:
gstffmpegdec.c(2804): gst_ffmpegdec_chain (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/ffdec_h264:ffdec_h2640:
ffdec_h264: input format was not set before data start
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

I know that the best way to capture video is using Muxers but is there any way to play my previous files?

Thanks

Comment: maybe you can try to set the mediatype between fdsrc and ffdec_h264. something like `video/x-h264, format=...`.

Comment: Thanks Wimmel, I tried your solution:    
  
    cat vid.bin | gst-launch fdsrc ! video/xh264, framerate=\(fraction\)10/1, format=\(fourcc\)I420, width=640, height=480 ! ffdec_h264 ! autovideosink    

Unfortunately, this method did not solve the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure your pipeline is right.

If you want to write to a file why not simply use filesink and filesrc.

fdsink > vid.bin will not work fine because if you see the prints by gstreamer gst-launch will also go into the file. [Just open vid.bin in an text editor and you will see what I mean].

Also for x264 stream to be stored without a muxer you need to use byte-stream=1 in your x264enc to store it in annexb format so that it is decodable.

To play back raw x264 stream you need to have a color space convertor before the video sink

```
gst-launch filesrc location=inputfile ! legacyh264parse ! ffdec_h264 ! queue ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink
```

plays just fine here at my end

Answer (score 2):

Or, to playback a raw h264 file with gstreamer 1.0:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=/tmp/video.h264 ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink
```

Comment: I had to replace avdev_h264 with ffdec_h264, to get this solution working